# Appending divs on mouseenter

Tags: jquery

Basically, I want to append a div to an `li` element on mouseenter, then append a separate div on mouseenter of another `li` element of the same parent `ul`.  So if an `li` is hovered, append `#div1`, then if another `li` is hovered, append `#div2`.

This is what I have so far

```
$('ul > li').mouseenter(function (){
      $('#div1').appendTo(this);

      if (('ul > li').mouseenter().not(this)){
         $('#div2')appendTo(this);
      }
});
```

This only appends `#div1` to the hovered `li`.  How do I append `#div2` if another `li` is hovered?  The `.not()` selector doesn't seem to be working.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('li').mouseenter(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            i = that.index();
        if (i == 0){
            $('#div1').appendTo(that);
        }
        else {
            $('#div2').appendTo(that);
        }
    });
```

The above is based on the assumption that you wish to append `#div1` to the first `li`, and `#div2` to all other `li` elements.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP (left below):

> I actually want to append #div1 on mouseenter then if another li is hovered, i'd like to append #div2 to the same li that #div1 was appended to.

```
$('li').mouseenter(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            i = that.index();
        if (i == 0){
            $('#div1').appendTo(that);
        }
        else {
            $('#div2').appendTo($('#div1').closest('li'));
        }
    })
```

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Thanks, I actually want to append `#div1` on `mouseenter` then if another `li` is hovered, i'd like to append `#div2` to the same `li` that `#div1` was appended to.  I hope this makes sense, it's actually for a menu animation I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could place the divs inside the `li` elements with `display:none` and just display them on mouseover.  You could fadeIn/etc..

**CSS**

```
li div {display:none}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>Whatever <div>the div </div></li>
<li>Whatever 2<div>the div 2</div></li>
<li>Whatever 3<div>the div 3</div></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('li').mouseenter(
function(){
    $('div', this).show(); //
});
```